# how to automatically open the camera

Tags: html, reactjs

To capture the image from mobile using React js code, I am using the following code

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture onChange={this.loadFile}/>
```

This input tag is dependent on the state variables in reacting. When the input tag gets rendered, firstly it will ask the user to click the "choose file "button and then will open the camera.
So, can we open the camera directly such that the "Choose File" button doesn't come and directly on changing the state values the camera gets open?
The loadFile handler function is :-

```
loadFile = (event: any) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      output: HTMLImageElement;
      var output = document.getElementById("output");
      output.src = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    // console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    this.setState({
      activeCameraToggle: 0,
      photo1: event.target.files[0]
    });
  };
```

Comment: Please share your handler function code?

Comment: updated the Question

Comment: Change `accept` from  `"image/*"` to `"image/*;capture=camera"`.

Comment: it didn't worked @JediBurrell, i want that the button "choose file" don't come and the camera opens directly

Comment: I would hate it, if you could open the camera without my accept!

Comment: @PoulBak You can't, the user would have to click on the `input` element to open it.

Comment: @JeriBurrell, well, you have answered the OP's question then.

Comment: @rockz It turns out the previous method no longer works, and the solution W3 provides is to use the MediaStream API. This is a much heavier solution that only saves the user one click. Why exactly do you want to skip the prompt?

Comment: share your function in detail

Answer (score 0):

Check this library:

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker

After adding it to your project do this:

```
// Launch Camera:
ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response)  => {
 // Same code as in above section!
});
```

Comment: Is this a react native project? It looks like the question is about web based React.